# Which would be the more efficient design for a 10 kW micro steam turbine - axial or radial?

Tags: turbines, steam

I'm aware of the inefficiencies of down scaling turbines due to boundary layer proportions to the laminar flow, but if say you'd have to design a 10 kW steam turbine, what would be the best design?

Impulse turbines seem to be a better choice than reaction turbines from my uneducated understanding so far. But small turbines make me think maybe a radial design would be better than an axial one.

For help of understanding, let's just assume steam is provided at 100 bar pressure from a monotube boiler if that helps. That means there is some high pressure to be considered. Does that even make any sense in that scale or would you be better off with a reciprocating design? (Obviously not an old-fashioned steam engine, in which 100 bar are not even remotely workable due to many reasons.)

Comment: What mass flow rate at 100 bar?

Comment: The flow rate would be dependent on the power and design. I guess in the ball park of 100kg/h would be the order of magnitude to look into for a 10KW turbine.

Comment: More likely 3 times your number and you might need to read this: https://www.repo.uni-hannover.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/3639/Rautenberg%20et%20al%201988%2C%20Design%20and%20Testing%20of%20a%2010KW%20Steam%20Turbine%20for%20Steam%20Turbochargers.pdf?sequence=1

Answer (score 0):

An Impulse turbine is more mechanically simple.
If you wanna increase pressure, I may suggest best thing to do ironically is get one off the shelf.

Siemens 3.5 Kilowatt D-R 2TA steam turbine.
[image]

Comment: That turbine is rated for 3.6 MW, not KW. I also ask for educational purposes.

Comment: Whoops, Wrong pic.